# Schema not writing to csv even if header=true is set

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create an empty dataframe and simply writing it to csv file.I was expecting schema will get written to file as I have specified header=true while writing but its creating empty .csv file.

I have tried setting different properties but nothing is working.

```
object HeaderTest extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("learning 
  spark").getOrCreate
  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  import spark.implicits._

  val df: DataFrame = Seq.empty[(String, Int)].toDF("k", "v")

  val f = "E:\\data.csv"
  df.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv(f)

 }
```

Comment: This path: `E:\\data.csv` should be a folder with multiple `part-...` files. Is the header missing for one of those files or all the files? Which spark version are you using?

Comment: the path is correct sai, it writes data when data is there in dataframe, path is not an issue, my spark version is 2.4, just found out its a known issue:
https://forums.databricks.com/questions/17398/write-empty-dataframe-into-csv.html